# Use IAM authentication AND a regular password to access AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Is it possible to set up a MySQL user that can login with IAM authentication AND a regular password? To be clear, I want to know if there can be a user that can access the RDS instance with either option (use IAM auth one day and then use a password the next day).

Answer (score 0):

I thought the answer was yes but according to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Limitations):

> For PostgreSQL, if the IAM role (rds_iam) is added to the master user, IAM authentication takes precedence over Password authentication so the master user has to log in as an IAM user.

The iam authentication will take precedence over the password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling IAM DB authentication, you can use any one authentication mechanism for one user (unless you alter user before logging in).

if you query mysql.user table, for IAM DB authenticated user,

```
+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| User    | plugin                  | authentication_string  |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| satya   | AWSAuthenticationPlugin | RDS                    |
```

You have to alter user before every login.

```
ALTER USER 'satya'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

if you query mysql.user table, for MySQL navtive authenticated user,

```
+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| User    | plugin                  | authentication_string  |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| satya   | mysql_native_password   | *ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD     |
```